# Dataframe add column: with count of rows where condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have got a dataframe (df) in python with 2 columns: ID and Date.

```
| ID            | Date          |
| ------------- |:-------------:|
| 1             | 06-14-2019    |
| 1             | 06-10-2019    |
| 2             | 06-16-2019    |
| 3             | 06-12-2019    |
| 3             | 06-12-2019    |
```

I'm trying to add a column to the dataframe which contains the count of rows where ID matches ID of the current row and Date <= Date of the current row. 
  Like the following:

```
| ID            | Date          | Count         |
| ------------- |:-------------:|:-------------:|
| 1             | 06-14-2019    | 2             |
| 1             | 06-10-2019    | 1             |
| 2             | 06-16-2019    | 1             |
| 3             | 06-12-2019    | 2             |
| 3             | 06-12-2019    | 2             |
```

I have tried something like:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ID'])   
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda row: grouped.get_group[row['ID']][grouped.get_group(row['ID'])['Date'] < row['Date']]['ID'].size, axis=1)
```

This results in the following error:
`TypeError: ("'method' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0')`

Suggestions are welcome

I forgot to mention:
My real dataframe contains almost 4 million rows, so i'm looking for a smart and fast solution that won't take to long to run

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.iterrows()`:

```
df['Count'] = None
for idx, value in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[idx, -1 ] = len(df[(df.ID == value[0]) & (df.Date <= value[1])].index)
```

**Output:**

```
+---+----+------------+-------+
|   | ID |    Date    | Count |
+---+----+------------+-------+
| 0 |  1 | 06-14-2019 |     2 |
| 1 |  1 | 06-10-2019 |     1 |
| 2 |  2 | 06-16-2019 |     1 |
| 3 |  3 | 06-12-2019 |     2 |
| 4 |  3 | 06-12-2019 |     2 |
+---+----+------------+-------+
```